# How to hide the android Keyboard after typing?

Tags: android-layout, android-xml

I just created a dialogfragment. and This fragment xml code is as bellow ...

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/button_layout_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/timeLayout"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
                android:text="Not Set"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/time_textView"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/button_layout_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
            android:layout_below="@id/timeLayout"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
                android:text="Not Set"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/title_textView"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/button_layout_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/foodmanuLayout"
            android:layout_below="@id/titleLayout"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
                android:text="Food Menu"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
                android:text="Not Set"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/foodmenu_textView"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Now when I run my appliation. I can write by clicking into the layout. But the problem is at a certain time the keyboard don't get hide (before completing typing for all layout). And because of this keyboard, I can not see the next layout content. So if I click the back button then the dialog fragment get dissmiss.  I tried to add the ScrollView but it also doesn't work. So need suggestion. Can Someone tell me

Here is my Dynamic EditText Code... I tried to use the InputMethodManager but Couldn't make it ...

```
  private void showTitle(){
       final EditText titleBox = new EditText(getActivity());
       titleBox.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       titleBox.setHint("Add Title");
       if(!titleView.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Not Set")){
         titleBox.setText(titleView.getText());
       }
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
       builder.setView(titleBox);
      /* InputMethodManager methodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       methodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(titleBox.getWindowToken(),0);*/
       builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
              String text = titleBox.getText().toString();
              if(text == null || text.isEmpty()){
                  titleView.setText("Not Set");
              }else{
                  titleView.setText(text);

              }

           }
       });
       builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
              dialogInterface.dismiss();
           }
       });
       builder.create().show();
    }
```

Comment: where are the EditText views??

Comment: I have edited the question. Here you will see a method. I tried to use the inputmethodmanager, but... I couldn't make it